# eXist-db query not using index

Tags: exist-db

I'm presently using eXist-db 2.2 on Windows 7, with 1.3gb of RAM allocated for Java.

I've been trying to optimize an XQuery:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $phrase := "flight"
let $nbsp := "&#32;"
    let $containing := collection("/db/MyDb")//value[contains(.,$phrase)]
    return (count($containing))
```

but this query always performs a scan on the database. My *collection.xconf* is as such:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <index>
        <fulltext default="none" attributes="false"/>
        <!-- create qname="value" content="mixed" /-->
        <lucene>
            <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
            <analyzer id="ws" class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer"/>
            <text qname="value" analyzer="ws"/>
        </lucene>
        <range>
            <create qname="value">
                <field name="value" match="value" type="xs:string" case="no"/>
            </create>
        </range>
    </index>
</collection>
```

The *value* node exist in multiple levels of the XML, so I was hoping that it will index this particular node regardless of where it's at in the tree.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can use the index?

Updated to include an XML fragment I'm using:

```
<v1 attribute1="b3492">
    <person>
        <sub id="b733" name="b733" />
        <section id="5897" label="a">
            <section id="e70e" label="a.a" >
                <field id="7e8a" label="a.a.f01">
                    <value type="String">test value</value>
                </field>
                <section id="78ea1" label="a.a.s01" >
                    <field id="7e8a" label="a.a.s01.f01">
                        <value type="String">test value 2</value>
                    </field>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </person>
</v1>
```

The size of the XML files I am using ranges from <10K to >2M. I have loaded about 12,000 of these files and a basic query takes upwards of 5 minutes at the moment.

An update --> I have updated the *collection.xconf* as following:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <index>
        <fulltext default="none" attributes="false"/>
        <!-- create qname="value" content="mixed" /-->
        <lucene>
            <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
            <analyzer id="ws" class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer"/>
            <text qname="value" analyzer="ws"/>
        </lucene>
        <range>
            <create qname="value" type="xs:string"/>
        </range>
    </index>
</collection>
```

The index now appears to be used, as the queries are returning results faster.. However "faster" here means that results are returned after about 1 minute, which is still too slow. Are there additional directives to improve index utilization?

Comment: For query/indexing question, please always attach an example XML fragment that is queried.

Answer (score 0):

Your index definition doesn't appear to match the [documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/newrangeindex.xml).

I think you should use

```
<range>
  <create qname="value" type="xs:string" />
</range>
```

Your current index is probably looking for value/value.

Comment: the sample code provided for `combined indexes` (look for it here: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/newrangeindex.xml) looks like so: 
`<range>
    <create qname="mods:name">
        <field name="name-type" match="@type" type="xs:string"/>
        <field name="name-part" match="mods:namePart" type="xs:string"/>
    </create>
</range>`

Comment: The example is for *combined* indexes, which probably do not apply in your case; You should have provided an XML fragment as well to be able to judge the query. user3787337 provided the same already.

Comment: thanks @DiZzZz, the original query was not written in that format, but in Exist 2.2 although the documentation mentions the possibility of using  `case="no"`, it was not possible to inject it on the create node.  I will update the query to the original setting sans the case issue and reply to this thread.

Comment: I have modified the collection.conf to match what was suggested. I guess I was confused about its utilization as the profiling page does not show it as being used still. As well, the query takes at least a minute before it returns the result. Are there options to improve the response time?

Comment: Did this answer help? If so, please mark it as the answer so that this question no longer shows up as "unanswered."